# To access user email from OAuth2.0?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I want to access the logged in user's email address from OAuth2.0. Just to make sure correct user have the rights to login.

Then I need to use this code:

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
}
```

Which are called from JavaScript:

```
<div>
     Logged in as: <span id="user"></span>
</div>

$.get("/user", function(data) { // Call Java code with GET request
   $("#user").html(data.userAuthentication.details.name); // Set id=user to the name of the user
});
```

But I want to access this from Java code, not JavaScript code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Spring Security defaults, you can cast the `Principal` to a `UserDetails` object and have access to everything you need for your use case:

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public Principal user(Principal principal) {

  UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) principal;
  System.out.println(userDetails.getUsername());
  System.out.println(userDetails.getPassword());
  System.out.println(userDetails.getAuthorities());

  // do whatever you want ... 

  return principal;
}
```

**UPDATE**: As you mentioned you use OAuth2, you can do the following to inject an authenticated OAuth2 principal:

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public Principal user(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) {

  // do whatever you want ... 

  return principal;
}
```

Comment: But when I calling the method user. What argument should I have then? Or do I need to do a HTTP get response from Java it self?

Comment: If the client is already authenticated in your Spring application, you can inject the `Principal` like you are already doing it

Comment: What authentication method does your application use? BasicAuth/FormLogin/OAuth2/etc.?

Comment: Im using oathLogin ()

Comment: Is '@RequestMapping("/user")' some kind of AutoWired injection?

Comment: No the dependency injection takes place at the method argument of your method `public Principal user(Principal principal)` here you claim to get a `Principal` injected from the Spring DI container

Comment: But I still need @RequestMapping ? Then I need to do a HTTP response to my server to get it, from my server.

Comment: Could not autowire `Principal principal` beacuse the bean has not been created yet.

Comment: Found it! https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Comment: By the way. This code won't work. Cannot cast the bean principal to UserDetails. `(UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();`

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example on how to inject an authenticated `OAuth2User`

Comment: No need to use HTTP requests. I'm not asking for it. I'm asking to get user information without HTTP requests. Your answer still helped me.

Comment: Ah okay, then just inject `@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal` anywhere in your code place where you know you have an authenticated user

Comment: Solved with this code: https://pastebin.com/NBhH8Mx6 Imporant with try-catch because if I'm not logged in, then the bean `principal` will not exist.